# Conditional formating based on values in two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Columns B, C with numeric values

On condition that    B=>C    B    should be colored red.

On condition that    B<C     B    should appear green.

Formula      ="B5=>C5"      Format: red background         Aplies to =$B$5:$B$100

Formula      ="B5<C5"       Format: green background       Aplies to =$B$5:$B$100

No error msg received, no color shows up.

Real chart as it appears in Excel - Conditional formating

[image: Printscreen]

Answer (score 0):

Mistake was in formula using quotes ="P5=>Q5"

Correct is =P5>=Q5 although it is mathematically nonsence.